# LINQ IQueryable returning same rows with skip and take

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, take

Using MVC Entity Framework I'm calling a function with AJAX that passes in skip and take parameters.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> _ViewMore( int take, int skip)
{
    var c = await GetContent( take, skip);
    return View(c)
}

public async Task<List<PartialContent>> GetContentForCulture(int take, int skip)
{           
    return await ContextHelper.SearchContent(take, skip);
}

public static async Task<List<PartialContent>> SearchContent( int take, int skip)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            var content = context.ContentEntities.SearchContent(take, skip);

            var f = await content.Select(s => new PartialContent
            {
                Subtype = s.Subtype,
                Id = s.Id,
                MainImage = s.MainImage,

            }).ToListAsync();

            return f;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //      Log.Err(ex.Message, ex);
        return null;
    }
}

public static IQueryable<T> SearchContent<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,  int take, int skip)
    where T : ContentEntity
{
    source.Where(m => m.IsPublished ).OrderByDescending(m => m.DatePublished).Skip(skip).Take(take)

}
```

My issue is that every time I call the function the same rows are returned even though I debug and the skip value increments, and I have 100s of rows to fetch from.

Comment: Yes, the same rows in the same order even though I increment skip by 12 each time.

Comment: Did you [trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) the EF calls?

Comment: I think you have more than one SearchContent() method.  The one with only take and skip has two parameters while the one posted has 8 parameters.

Comment: I removed the parameters to make it more readable

Comment: which entity framework version you are using?

Comment: Entity framework version  6.1.3

Comment: I need to directly see the source code directly calling SearchContent (your sample code is not). Show us how that IQueryable is getting constructed and how it's passing your parameters to the SearchContent you listed (and how it's handling the results).

Comment: I would suggest that the most obvious possible issue is if you're ordering criteria aren't sufficient to *uniquely* define the ordering of rows. E.g. if you have hundreds of rows with exactly the same `DatePublished` value then the system is behaving "correctly" since the same rows *could* have appeared in rows 1-12 or in rows 25-36.

Comment: Where's the GetContent(...) method?

Comment: you can see the generated sql statement by doing a `.ToString()` on the IQueryable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add another order by clause as suggested by Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score -2):

```
    //pageSize is how many rows you want to skip every time and 
    //index is like page number first time index should be 0 then 1 every time index will be increased by one 
    var c = await  context.ContentEntities.Skip(pageSize * index).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
```